# Problem with MySQL RENAME and CREATE TABLE statements clashing

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a problem where a RENAME statement clashes with a CREATE TABLE statement to cause deadlock.

I have a CREATE TABLE statement of the form

```
CREATE TABLE `ProductTitles`
(
    PRIMARY KEY (`ProductId`),
    INDEX ( `Title`, `ProductScore` )
)    
SELECT p.ProductId, p.Title, ps.ProductScore
FROM Products p
JOIN ProductScores ps USING (ProductId)
```

Due to table sizes, this can take around 30 minutes to complete.

The problem occurs when this statement is running when another process tries to replace the Products table using a RENAME statement of the form:

```
RENAME TABLE
Products TO ProductsOld, 
ProductsNew TO Products
```

This rename statement then locks the Products table for reads and writes until the CREATE TABLE statement has completed.

My question is how do I avoid this situation?

Is is possible to use locks, or perhaps querying for the presence of a CREATE TABLE statement, to avoid running the RENAME statement until the CREATE statement is done?

As far as I can tell, this occurs whether using MyISAM or InnoDb.  There must be some mechanism to protect against this happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you use myisam count() is very quick, you could compare the sizes of Products to ProductTitles before attempting the rename

Answer (score 0):

Renaming tables isn't the best way to do what you're doing. It would be better to use a script to write all the data from Products to ProductsOld and delete it from Products.